# Mock partially a class with scalamock

Tags: scala, scalamock

I'm trying to test a class `Cls` with two functions: `A` and `B`. `A` loads a `DataFrame` and `B` calls `A` then does some operations and returns a new `DataFrame`. For the sake of example:

```scala
class Cls {
    def A(dummy: Int): Int = 5
    def B(): Int = A(7) + 1
}
```

With `Scalamock` how can write my test code ?

I tried:

```scala
test("test case") {
  val f = stub[Cls]
  f.A _ when 7 returns 5
  assert(f.B() == 6)
}
```

I expect test passed successfully and I get `0 did not equal 6 (mytestcase.scala:24)` (I do understand that that scalamock replaced all existing functions with mock however this is not the intended behavior)

Edit:
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14970545/11305442) which references this [concept](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks) in mockito but I'm not sure if scalamock supports this kind of mocking and why it's advised against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScalaMock does not override/stub final methods. So your solution could be to create a subclass with parts of the method marked as final:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class PartialMockingTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory {

  test("test case") {

    class PartFinalCls extends Cls {
      override final def B(): Int = super.B()
    }

    val f = stub[PartFinalCls]
    f.A _ when 7 returns 5
    assert(f.B() == 6)
  }

}

class Cls {
  def A(dummy: Int): Int = 5
  def B(): Int = A(7) + 1
}
```

Comment: Very interesting Idea. I wonder if there is a way that doesn't involve creating a new class

Comment: Sorry, no. I maintain ScalaMock as a project and this is the only way i can recommend at the moment.